# What's the point in setting a variable to nil first before instantiating it in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, static

I've just started learning Objective C for iOS development. I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BirdSightingCell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:sightingAtIndex.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];
    return cell;
}
```

Question 1:

What does "static" do while declaring the variables CellIdentifier and formatter? It still works if I don't declare them static so what's the advantage of using static?

Q2:

```
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if (formatter == nil) {
```

Isn't this expression always true? Why do we use that if statement there?

Comment: It is a static variable so, it sets the nil for the first time only when the method executes. For the first time it checks if the variable is nil and then creates it and in the subsequent calls, the formatter is static and so once it is created it remains there but the scope is limited inside the method only. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` in this context means, that it's a "shared" variable across multiple calls to this method. The first time it is called, the static variable will be `nil`. The next time it will be what ever it was set to during the last call.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` means that the variable is set to `nil` once, at program startup, not every time you 'run' that statement, and that it maintains its value across multiple function calls.

Hence the first time you call that function, it will be `nil` and the `if` statement will fire. Subsequent calls to the function will have it set to a non-`nil` value so that the code in the `if` statement won't run again.

This is called lazy initialisation.